# Flash plugin "unresponsive" if application is in fullscreen

Tags: windows-7, firefox, flash

if I have a website with anything flash open, and I open another application such as Powder toy, VLC, etc in Fullscreen mode, Firefox will rudely minimize the application to tell me "the flash plugin is unresponsive" with the option to continue or wait. wait just makes the browser unable to restore and display anything for a few seconds before asking the question again, and close closes the flash plugin. the browser isn't running out of memory, so it seems weird that it would stop responding just because it's not focused anymore.
before marking as a duplicate of flash crashing in full screen, it is important to note that flash is not the application being run in full screen. flash is in it's frame like normal, for example in an ad or in Grooveshark. opening a windows application that goes fullscreen is what makes it crash.

Comment: What Firefox and Flash Player version are you using?

Comment: flash 13
FireFox 28